# Increment Counter when click on Link

Tags: php

Dear All :  Just to give more information , I have a search panel when certain criteria is given it fetch record from database and it display record .

```
<div id="menubar"> 
  <ul>
    <li class="current_page_item">
      <a href="count.php" name="abc<?php $i; ?>">Home</a>
      <?php $_SESSION['Home']=$row['ID']; echo $_SESSION['Home'];?>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div id="menubar">
  <ul>
    <li class="current_page_item">
      <a href="count.php" name="abc<?php $i; ?>">Home</a>
      <?php $_SESSION['Home']=$row['ID']; echo $_SESSION['Home'];?>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

so now what i want is either type-1 : so now if one click on 1st record home link it will take page a.php and when click on record 2nd it should take to b.php . and record are generated dynamically how we will change the page name ie is ( a.php and b.php ) OR any other solution . what i want to do is for each page that is a.php or b.php i want to store how many time the page have been visited and store that counter in database

Comment: Why not just use google analytics? Better than anything you could take two years to write.

Comment: Do you want the counter on a.php / b.php or on this main page here?

Comment: @Emyr there are a lot of reason to not use Google Analytics in this case, say that they want to sort the links by clicks or something like that - impossible with Google Analytics obviously.

Comment: Dear Connor : Thanks for the reply , yes on search page there are dynamic record which are fetch from database , so when someone click on 1st record it should go to say for eg : a.php and then i will write on a.php page mysql update query which will update the counter . But what i dont understand is on search page there are dynamic result . so on that page how i will change the name of link say 2 record are fetch , so for 1st record when link click a.php and then for 2nd record when link click b.php . please advice if possible with code

Answer (score 0):

The easiest version would to to have a function which will be called on a.php and b.php just writing a new visit record into the database. As you know which page was called it is very easy to save that page request.

page.php

```
$mysqli->query('UPDATE counts SET count = count + 1 WHERE page = '.$mysqli->real_escape_string($_REQUEST['page']);
```

html page:

```
<div id="menubar"> 
  <ul>
    <li class="current_page_item">
      <a href="count.php?page=<?php echo $row['ID'] ?>" name="abc<?php echo $i; ?>">Home</a>
      <?php $_SESSION['Home']=$row['ID']; echo $_SESSION['Home'];?>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Dear Connor : Thanks for the reply , yes on search page there are dynamic record which are fetch from database , so when someone click on 1st record it should go to say for eg : a.php and then i will write on a.php page mysql update query which will update the counter . But what i dont understand is on search page there are dynamic result . so on that page how i will change the name of link say 2 record are fetch , so for 1st record when link click a.php and then for 2nd record when link click b.php . please advice if possible with code

Comment: say for eg there are 1000 record i cant keep creating pages like a.php , b.php and so on.... for 1000 record .

Comment: So why are you then telling us, that there are pages like a.php, b.php, and so on. Just use one php file and use parameter. Like `count.php?page=a`, `count.php?page=b` and so on.

Comment: say for eg there are 1000 record i cant keep creating pages like a.php , b.php and so on.... for 1000 record .My main problem is on say search.php page there are 2 record fetch from database         1st record :  <li class="current_page_item"><a href="count.php" name="abc<?php $i; ?>">Home</a><?php $_SESSION['Home']=$row['ID']; echo $_SESSION['Home'];?></li>                                         2nd record :  <li class="current_page_item"><a href="count.php" name="abc<?php $i; ?>">Home</a><?php $_SESSION['Home']=$row['ID']; echo $_SESSION['Home'];?></li>. So when $row['ID'] run in loop last

Comment: Dear Kau-Boy : Thanks for reply , can you please give the example in code , i would be realy thankful as i am stuck and i am not getting how to do it